# How to specify implied types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to create a `Pipe` interface in TypeScript, the only constraint is that when the pipe-through is done, I want it to return the same type as what came in:

```
Pipe.pour(liquid).through(somePipelines) => typeof liquid
```

This is how I currently approach this:

A *Pipe* interface that can run some stuff through an array of `Pipeline`s:

```
interface IPipe<SomeLiquidType> {
    liquid: SomeLiquidType,
    pour: (liduid: SomeLiquidType) => IPipe<SomeLiquidType>
    through: (pipelines: Array<(input: SomeLiquidType) => SomeLiquidType>) => SomeLiquidType,
}
```

And this is an implementation of the pipe interface

```
const Pipe: IPipe<unknown> = {
    liquid: null,

    pour(somethingToPour) {
        this.liquid = somethingToPour;

        return this;
    },

    through(pipelines) {
        for (const pipeline of pipelines) {
            this.liquid = pipeline(this.liquid)
        }

        return this.liquid;
    }
}
```

The idea is that any object that implements this `Pipe` interface should be able to `pour()` any liquid `through()` an array of pipelines.

Now, I created some pipelines to try this out:

```
function addSugar( liquid: Juice ){
    ...
    return liquid;
}

function addStrawberryFlavour( liquid: Juice ){
    ...
    return liquid;
}
```

And then use the Pipe service

```
const juice = GetSodaWater();

Pipe
    .pour(juice)
    .through([addSugar, addStrawberryFlavour])
```

I am getting error similar to:

> Type '(addSugar: Juice) => Juice' is not assignable to type '(input: unknown) => unknown'.

It is clear that `(input: unknown) => unknown` in the error above is coming from `IPipe<unknown>`, but I do not know how to fix this. I have tried `IPipe<any>` but that results in another loop of problems.

How do I implement this Pipe without these weird errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the conceptual problem here is that after the `pour` call the pipe becomes a pipe of Juice. You could model this by making `pour` generic and returning a `IPipe` of a specific liquid that is returned.

```
interface IPipe<SomeLiquidType = unknown> {
    liquid: SomeLiquidType,
    pour: <SpecificLiquid extends SomeLiquidType>(liduid: SpecificLiquid) => IPipe<SpecificLiquid>
    through: (pipelines: Array<(input: SomeLiquidType) => SomeLiquidType>) => SomeLiquidType,
}

const Pipe: IPipe = {
    liquid: null,

    pour<T>(somethingToPour: T) {
        this.liquid = somethingToPour;

        return this as IPipe<T>;
    },

    through(pipelines) {
        for (const pipeline of pipelines) {
            this.liquid = pipeline(this.liquid)
        }

        return this.liquid;
    }
}

//../
Pipe
    .pour(juice)
    .through([addSugar, addStrawberryFlavour])
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAVgAcIB4DKA9gLYQAywAjgK7AAmAKgJ47IC8y1IA1iIQO4gAfMgDeAWABQyGcgA2VWnQBcyIqQo16zHABops5FkLUoqgjgTAYwBJqXIIAD0gg6AZzUlyi7SwhCABQKdEqq+JbWtvb0AJTsIhjYeBEQVjZ2vnRCBrJgABZQJgDm+aqBWMkKIBDuqgCCUFBwTLiBoFjUYOHeMYz+8Wwi6j5a-ThCg8O9WToQ+pIAvlJSCIQg7mDImDiqSawcEtKyCmOqINRycgu5MsamuAxB7t4FoMUMhOgmZsgM8UdDIY3u4AHSnBwcF6kN4gD5fH4AbhWxyByCgEDAphAyBByDgnn2eCeyNRyEWNzJBSK1FKFSqoFqANuQJghCgyECaw2W0qOGqKEIMCMDJq7mZZLRMhB4Ky7BF-MZgRlELiLMMy0k6tkGKxUBxKqypI1Uk1CDkBM8AClaEgxJqYFwEGBgOt8XQ6PhaXAoIF5FlVDbbChYoCdZjsf6xqTNVJHSBna6cXAPfgwM1+AAjaBQJgAMQtADcfn7VSpkEG7aHkCzdZGyzHVutNsgAFa2lAcGr8CsdwKxUk7CAs0H3X3t4OxEfUkr5QIAbRTnu9UF07s96bgWZz+aLPwAulPJEA)

Comment: This is genius! Thanks man. So, my knowledge gap is that I did not know that I can specify a default value for types as in `<SomeLiquidType = unknown>` (and I noticed that using `any` here fails). Please advise on how I can fill this knowledge gap (no part of TypeScript Guide/Handbook indicates that types can be assigned default values). Thank you.

Comment: @DamilolaOlowookere I can't recommend a specific book or course. My profile has some more videos about Ts if you want to watch. But none of them would have covered the possibility of defaults for type parameters either ‍♂️